# cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I 'm trying to build an android app but I'm stuck in the same error.
Android Studio can't find symbol method setContentView(int) and findViewById(int).
Here is the code:

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_news);

    WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

    WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
    mainWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    mainWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}

private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Fragment`,not `Activity`.If you want to use activity,please make your class implements `Activity` instead of `Fragment`.

If you want to use Fragment,you should set view in onCreateView,like this:

```
private WebView mainWebView;
protected View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle data){
    View view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news,vg,false);
    mainWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are extending `Fragment` and `setContentView` is a method of Activity not of `Fragment`. You can either change your class to extend `Activity` or keep using `Fragment` and override `onCreateView` to inflate and return an instance of  `fragment_news`, and use it to retrive the widgets it contains